# Hook a lookup to column jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Data tables.

In one of the columns in a data table I want to display data in a select box with the actual value of that cell as the selected value.

Is there any way to hook a lookup table to the column such that each cell of that column is hooked with a lookup table?

If the user wants to update value of that particular cell can the user can select any of the values from the select box?

Comment: That is indeed possible, what have you tried?

Comment: using the render option for that column

Comment: @annoyingmouse Yes i have tried the same way Bindrid did.

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsbin.com/solipe/edit?html,js,output

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // create fake column to put in selectbox
    for(var i = 0; i < dataStore.data.length; ++i){
       var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
       dataStore.data[i].groupId = b;
    }

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": dataStore.data,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "groupId"},
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }], 
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columnDefs:[{targets:[1], 
            render:function(a,b,c,d){
                var str = "";
                for(var j = 1; j < 11; ++j){
                    str += "<option " +(j == a? " selected ":"")+"  value='" + j + "'>"  + j + "</option>";
                }
                str = "<select>" + str + "</select>";
                return str;
           }}]

    } );
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Bindrid, 
I am following the same approach. 

I just wanted to know if there is any simpler way where we can just say that hey this is the lookup table for this column and then it internally hooks the lookup with cells (list in lookup table as options in select box )with the actual value as selected option.

Comment: Could you please help?

Comment: I don't think it get much simpler than this.  DataTables does not have any automated feature that I know of.  My sample code doe take the value in the cell and make it the selected value when the table loads. It also has a change event handler to keep the datatable data in sync with the select box.  Look at the link, if you haven't already, to see the full logic.